# why ajax call is not made to spring Controller what changes should I do?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I need to fetch 2 numbers from a text feild during a button click event in html and JS and then pass those values to spring mvc controller through ajax.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("myBtn");
button.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  var v1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
var v2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
var str = {"value1":  v1 , "value2":v2};
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/Cloudnet/login/addNumber", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(str));
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  console.log(xmlhttp.response);
 }
}
```

```html
<br>
<label for="n1">first number:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="n1">
<label for="n2">second number:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="n2">
<br>
<button type="button" id="myBtn" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${path}/js/cloudnet/cloudnet.js"></script>
<%-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" href="<c:url value="/addItem.jsp"/>">Click</button> --%>
  </div>
```

---

I have aslo attached my Spring controller snippet

---

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addNumber", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String controllerMethod(@RequestBody DataRequest request){
    Integer value1 = request.getValue1();
    Integer value2 = request.getValue2();
    System.out.println("values :"+value1+" , "+value2);
    int result=value1+value2;
    System.out.println(result);
    String res=Integer.toString(result);
    return res;
}
```

My pojo class details :
I am directly passing this pojo inside controller

```
  public class DataRequest {
    private Integer value1;
    private Integer value2;
    public Integer getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }
    public void setValue1(Integer value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }
    public Integer getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }
    public void setValue2(Integer value2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
    }
}
```

---

Comment: have you tried removing login from path ? sending to Cloudnet/addNumber?

Comment: But that method is inside login controller which has request mapping value of “/login”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@RequestBody` annotated parameter is expected to hold the entire body of the request and bind to one object. 
Change your controller method like following:

```
public class DataRequest {
    private Integer value1;
    private Integer value2;

    public Integer getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public void setValue1(Integer value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }

    public Integer getValue2() {
        return Value2;
    }

    public void setValue2(Integer value2) {
        Value2 = value2;
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addNumber", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String controllerMethod(@RequestBody DataRequest request){
    Integer value1 = request.getValue1();
    Integer value2 = request.getValue2();
    System.out.println("values :"+value1+" , "+value2);
    int result=value1+value2;
    System.out.println(result);
    String res=Integer.toString(result);
    return res;
}
```

For js, try something like this:

```
var v1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
var v2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
var str = "{value1:} + v1 + ", value2:" + v2 + "}";
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/Cloudnet/login/addNumber", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(str));
```

Comment: Thanks for replying are you say that we have to pass pojo entity to controller if so then what changes I should do in JS and html

Comment: Thanks for replying ...Are you say that we have to pass pojo entity to controller ? if so then what changes I should do in JS and html...

Comment: error in my chrome console log:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: That's something with your context path. Please set them correctly.

Comment: Sorry I’m new to web development can you explain in detail about what is context path and where it is....?It will be so helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell Spring properly where are your resources (JavaScript and/or CSS files) located. In your Spring context configuration you should have mapping for resources like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

Make sure the `location` points to your `/src/main/webapp/resources` folder. In the folder you should have the `./js/cloudnet.js` file. On your JSP you can access this JavaScript file like this:

```
<spring:url var="js" value="/resources/js/cloudnet.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${js}"></script>
```

If you need more details of how it is configured, I have just put the working example of your (slightly modified) code [here](https://github.com/yaskovdev/sandbox/tree/master/question-47738423).